# Method with ConditionalAttribute called with another method call in parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on .NET C# (Xamarin.Forms specifically). I don't know much about how the compiler/runtime work with `ConditionalAttribute` behind the scenes.

If I have a method with `System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute` defined. Something like this :

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void LogDebug(string tag, string message, params object[] args)
{
  DoSomeThing(tag, message);
  SomeLogLibrary.Log($"[{tag}] {message}", args);
}
```

And I call it with

```
LogDebug("Log data={0}", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(somedata));
```

The question is : Does the `SerializeObject` called when `DEBUG` is not defined?

It matters if `SerializeObject` or some other method do the hard work only to print it out for logging *(I think serializing object is a hard work)*. And I don't want it to work unless I'm debugging.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not simply try it out? Call your own method in there, set a breakpoint and debug it in Release mode...

Comment: @ChrFin Thanks. I absolutely forgot I can try with my own method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the entire method call will be removed.

See also the explanation on Microsoft Docs ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#the-conditional-attribute)):

> If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call
>   (including evaluation of the receiver and parameters of the call) is
>   omitted.